# How to design regex pattern?

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to extract words in numbers and letters from sentence mixed with special characters. How to design regex pattern?

```
/[^\s|^~!@\#$%<>^&*\()\-=+_\’,.|^\\t]([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/g
```

The code is as follows

```
let str = `\ttdccb`;
let re = /[^\s|^\\t|^~!@\#$%<>^&*\()\-=+_\’,.]([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/g;
strArray = str.match(re);
```

I expect the output of `\ttdccb` to be `tdccb`, but the actual output is `dccb`.

**update:**

before

```
let str = `abcd 0001 \\thi\\t
HA
 ABC \\t\\ttag,
tag
 taag`
```

expect

```
["abcd", "0001", "hi", "HA", "ABC", "tag", "tag", "taag"]
```

actual

```
["abcd", "0001", "hi", "HA", "ABC", "ag", "ag", "aag"]
```

Comment: Please look (again) into character classes (`[...]`), you're using them absolutely wrong.

Comment: `[^\s|^\\t|^~!@\#$%<>^&*\()\-=+_\’,.]` matches any char but whitespace...some more chars... and also other than `t`. Thus you can't expect the match to start with `t`.  Please update the problem description, add more clarifications, the question is too unclear. Especially, the "words in numbers and letters from sentence mixed with special characters" definition.

Comment: Play in Regex101.com

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I'm sorry, I updated example

Comment: `str.match(/\w+/g)` => `["abcd", "0001", "hi", "HA", "ABC", "tag", "tag", "taag"]`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew oh, the example I updated was wrong Please check one more

Comment: `str.replace(/\\t/g,'').match(/\w+/g)` => `["abcd", "0001", "hi", "HA", "ABC", "tag", "tag", "taag"]` - BUT there are combinations of ``\`` and `t`, that is not a special character, not a whitespace.

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Please also consider upvoting if my answer proved helpful to you (see [How to upvote on Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow)) as you are entitled to the upvoting privilege after reaching 15 rep points. Note you may upvote all the answers that turned out helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have backslash+`t` char combinations in the input string. You want to get all words free from `\t` 2-char combinations. Just replace them with some non-word char, say a comma, before extracting with `/\w+/g`:

```
str.replace(/\\t/g,',').match(/\w+/g)
```

See the JS demo:

```js
var str = 'abcd 0001 \\thi\\t\nHA\n ABC \\t\\ttag,\ntag\n taag';
console.log(str.replace(/\\t/g,',').match(/\w+/g));
// => ["abcd", "0001", "hi", "HA", "ABC", "tag", "tag", "taag"]
```

Comment: in case,
``let str = `p00e\\t\\tp000a` ``
I expect `["p00e","p00a"]`. But result was `["p00ep00a"]`. So, I modified your solution.
Like that,
``str.replace(/\\t/g,',').match(/\w+/g)``